# Intuitively what does it mean for a discrete RV to have no expectation?

Tags: probability

I wanted to know what it would mean intuitively for a discrete random variable to have no expectation.

Some things I was thinking of is that the amount you would expect to pay in order to have a fair game is an infinite amount of money?

Comment: That is one example among many.  To "have no expectation" carries with it the same connotations that other questions about limits not existing have.  Maybe that is because the "limit" is infinity as your suggested example.  Maybe its because it continually fluctuates between certain points.  Maybe its because it continues a seemingly random path and doesn't settle down into a predictable pattern...

Comment: yeah im having trouble understanding what it means intuitively in a general sense.

Comment: In certain models the [Pareto distribtion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution)  is used which has infinite mean for $\alpha\le 1$. The intuition is exactly what you say. Suppose you were an insurance that hat to pay for such Pareto distributed losses. It would be impossible for you to finance the expected loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that might help with your intuition: one common interpretation of the expected value is of the "long-run average." That is, if you repeatedly run an experiment whose outcome is the random variable, you might take the average of the values, and that average should converge to $\mu$.

But, this presupposes that the long-run average converges at all; it doesn't have to. Here are some examples of simulations in R with various different variables. For each one, I'll compute the average of 100 copies of the variable a few times -- then, I'll compute the average of 100,000 copies of the variables a few times.

##### Variable 1: D6 roll (uniform on $\{1, 6\}$; $\mu = 3.5$)

```
> set.seed(5920)
> # n = 100:
> mean(sample(1:6, 100, replace = T))
[1] 3.4
> mean(sample(1:6, 100, replace = T))
[1] 3.49
> mean(sample(1:6, 100, replace = T))
[1] 3.68
> # n = 100,000
> mean(sample(1:6, 100000, replace = T))
[1] 3.49614
> mean(sample(1:6, 100000, replace = T))
[1] 3.49883
> mean(sample(1:6, 100000, replace = T))
[1] 3.50227
```

All the averages are close to $\mu = 3.5$, but the ones based on 100,000 replicants are much closer.

##### Variable 2: Geometric with $p = 1/2$ ($\mu = 2$)

```
> set.seed(5920)
> # n = 100:
> mean(rgeom(100, 1/2) + 1) # need + 1 b/c rgeom() counts failures before success
[1] 1.76
> mean(rgeom(100, 1/2) + 1)
[1] 1.91
> mean(rgeom(100, 1/2) + 1)
[1] 2.14
> #n = 100,000
> mean(rgeom(100000, 1/2) + 1)
[1] 1.99764
> mean(rgeom(100000, 1/2) + 1)
[1] 1.99539
> mean(rgeom(100000, 1/2) + 1)
[1] 1.99805
```

Same thing here; all means are close to $\mu = 2$, and they're closer with more replications.

##### Variable 3: The St. Petersburg variable, $\mu = \infty$

This is the variable indicating the payout of a player in the game described in the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox). That is, it's $2^X$, where $X \sim \operatorname{Geom}(1/2)$.

```
> set.seed(5920)
> # n = 100
> mean(2^(rgeom(100, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 5.24
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 10.32
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 10.84
```

There's much less consistency here, so before throwing in more replicants, let's just try this again a few more times.

```
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 12.46
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 33.74
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 6.6
```

We see much greater fluctuations here. What happens when `n = 100000`?

```
> # n = 100,000
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100000, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 17.79764
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100000, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 20.60238
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100000, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 15.31172
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100000, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 19.77876
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100000, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 19.30214
> mean(2 ^ (rgeom(100000, 1/2) + 1))
[1] 53.77378
```

We see a few things here: first, these averages are generally higher than the $n = 100$ ones (though not all of them!), and it should match your intuition that the sample averages would drift upward to "chase" the true theoretical value of $\infty$. The more important feature is that the averages are still relatively unsettled and are subject to wild fluctuations -- unlike the other two examples. In a case where the expectation *really* doesn't exist at all (as opposed to being $\infty$, as was the case in this example), you might see this same behavior; the sample averages would "wander" and refuse to settle, even as the samples become large.

---

### Takeaway

There are lots of technical conditions and details I'm sweeping under the rug in this discussion. But, if you're looking for some quick intuition about what "does not have an expected value" means, then "**its sample averages do not converge, even when the sample sizes become huge**" is a pretty decent proxy.